# SIGABRT when trying to parse JSON

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to parse a JSON string but it falls with a SIGABRT error.

Code I am using:

```
NSString *test = @'{"notifications":[{"id":"fae9a890-2791-46e2-ad9c-5a72f602a2e8","created":"2017-06-17T21:57:28+00:00","thread_id":3964,"reply_id":null,"thread":{"id":3964,"subject":"[CakePHP] Pagination"},"users_from":{"username":"Royal"},"content":"has posted a reply in"},{"id":"00732627-f23e-423e-b885-add968575972","created":"2017-06-17T20:08:05+00:00","thread_id":3964,"reply_id":79478,"thread":{"id":3964,"subject":"[CakePHP] Pagination"},"users_from":{"username":"Royal"},"content":"has quoted you in"}]}';

 NSError *error;
        NSMutableDictionary *allCourses = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:test
                                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                                            error:&error];
        if( error )
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else {
            NSArray *monday = allCourses[@"notifications"];
            for ( NSDictionary *theCourse in monday )
            {
                NSLog(@"----");
                NSLog(@"Title: %@", theCourse[@"subject"] );
                NSLog(@"Id: %@", theCourse[@"id"] );
                NSLog(@"----");
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in your NSString declaration:

```
NSString *test = @'{"notifications"}';
```

This is wrong.

NSString must always use this format: @"bla bla bla".

You need to incorporate escapes for double quotes in your test string like this

```
NSString *test = @"{\"notifications\"}";
```

Comment: Works, thanks. Is there any way to do this automatically?

Comment: If it is me, I'd simply add a textfile in the project and type the json in there and then reading the texfile by code and load it into dictionary. that way u dont need to deal with escapes