# Parse json from URL in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to parse some JSON from a URL in objective C.

The output is fine, however, when I try to get the value of the notifications.id key it returns a SIGBRT error.

Code:

```
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:data
                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                 error:&serializeError];

     success = [jsonData[@"ERROR"] integerValue];

       if (success == 0) {
          NSLog(@"%@", jsonData[@"notifications"][@"id"]);
       }else{

       }
```

Example JSON is:

> {"notifications":[{"id":"fae9a890-2791-46e2-ad9c-5a72f602a2e8","created":"2017-06-17T21:57:28+00:00","thread_id":3964,"reply_id":null,"thread":{"id":3964,"subject":"[CakePHP]
>   Pagination"},"users_from":{"username":"Royal"},"content":"has posted a
>   reply
>   in"},{"id":"00732627-f23e-423e-b885-add968575972","created":"2017-06-17T20:08:05+00:00","thread_id":3964,"reply_id":79478,"thread":{"id":3964,"subject":"[CakePHP]
>   Pagination"},"users_from":{"username":"Royal"},"content":"has quoted
>   you in"}]}

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the JSON data you are trying to parse?

Comment: Show the JSON, also don't you have a message in console when it crashes? Like a "unrecognized selector sent to instance" or anything else?

Comment: If that's the JSON there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614580/sigabrt-when-trying-to-parse-json, then `jsonData[@"notifications"]` is an array not a dictionary, so it's `jsonData[@"notifications"][0][@"id"]`.

Comment: Thanks ^, that did work :), any idea on how to do it in a for loop?

Comment: @Anoniem add portion of your data, that will help to answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object for key `notifications` is clearly an array. Please read the JSON: `[]` is array, `{}` is dictionary.

```
NSArray *notifications = jsonData[@"notifications"];
for (NSDictionary * notification in notifications) {
     NSLog(@"%@", notification[@"id"]);
}
```